# I get error when I created one form with 2 entities mapped

Tags: forms, symfony

I have 2 entities, Topic.php and Post.php I would like to have this:

[image]

TopicType.php :

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class TopicType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('title', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'Titre'))
                ->add('subForm', new PostType())
                ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                    'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'btn right-flt')))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'bissap_forumbundle_topic';
    }
}
```

PostType.php :

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('content', 'ckeditor', array(
                    'label' => 'Votre message',
                    'config_name' => 'my_custom_config',
                    'config' => array('language' => 'fr')))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'bissap_forumbundle_post';
    }
}
```

Topic.php :

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/*use BISSAP\BodyConcept\Entity\Forum;
*/

/**
 * Topic
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\TopicRepository")
 */
class Topic
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Forum", inversedBy="Topics", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $forum;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $Posts
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="Topic", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
     */
    private $posts;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="Topics", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="view_count", type="integer")
     */
    private $viewCount;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_creation", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="reply_count", type="integer")
     */
    private $replyCount;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="genre", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $genre;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_post", type="integer")
     */
    private $lastPost;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param integer $user
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set viewCount
     *
     * @param integer $viewCount
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setViewCount($viewCount)
    {
        $this->viewCount = $viewCount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get viewCount
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getViewCount()
    {
        return $this->viewCount;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreation
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
    {
        $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreation
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateCreation()
    {
        return $this->dateCreation;
    }

    /**
     * Set replyCount
     *
     * @param integer $replyCount
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setReplyCount($replyCount)
    {
        $this->replyCount = $replyCount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get replyCount
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getReplyCount()
    {
        return $this->replyCount;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    /**
     * Set genre
     *
     * @param string $genre
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setGenre($genre)
    {
        $this->genre = $genre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get genre
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getGenre()
    {
        return $this->genre;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastPost
     *
     * @param integer $lastPost
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setLastPost($lastPost)
    {
        $this->lastPost = $lastPost;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastPost
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getLastPost()
    {
        return $this->lastPost;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set forum
     *
     * @param Forum $forum
     * @return Topic
     */
    /*public function setForum(\BISSAP\BodyConceptBundle\Entity\Forum $forum)*/
    public function setForum(Forum $forum)
    {
        $this->forum = $forum;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get forum
     *
     * @return \BISSAP\BodyConceptBundle\Entity\Forum 
     */
    public function getForum()
    {
        return $this->forum;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->dateCreation = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Add posts
     *
     * @param \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post $posts
     * @return Topic
     */
    public function addPost(\BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
    {
        $this->posts[] = $posts;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove posts
     *
     * @param \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post $posts
     */
    public function removePost(\BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
    {
        $this->posts->removeElement($posts);
    }

    /**
     * Get posts
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }
}
```

Post.php :

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="Posts", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_creation", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_modif", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateModif;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Topic", inversedBy="Posts", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $topic;



    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->dateCreation = new \DateTime();
    $this->dateModif = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreation
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
    {
        $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreation
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateCreation()
    {
        return $this->dateCreation;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateModif
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateModif
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setDateModif($dateModif)
    {
        $this->dateModif = $dateModif;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateModif
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateModif()
    {
        return $this->dateModif;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    /**
     * Set Topic
     *
     * @param Topic $topic
     * @return Post
     */
    /*public function setTopic(\BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic $topic)*/
    public function setTopic(Topic $topic)
    {
        $this->topic = $topic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Topic
     *
     * @return \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic 
     */
    public function getTopic()
    {
        return $this->topic;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setUser(\BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

And this is my part of my controller, here i call and use the form:

```
public function categoryAction(Request $request)
    {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $topic = new \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic();
        $form = $this->createForm(new TopicType(), $topic);

        $user = $this->getUser();
        $forum = $em->getRepository('BISSAPForumBundle:Forum')->find(1);

        if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

            $topic->setUser($user);
            $topic->setForum($forum);
            $topic->setViewCount(23);
            $topic->setReplyCount(123);
            $topic->setLastPost(25);
            $topic->setSlug('slug_sluggg');
            $topic->setGenre('genre');
            $em->persist($topic);
            $em->flush();


            return $this->render('BISSAPForumBundle:F:topic-forum.html.twig', array('user' => $user, 'topic' => $topic));
        }
            return $this->render('BISSAPForumBundle:F:category-forum.html.twig', array('listTopics' => $listTopics, 'catId' => $catId, 'form' => $form->createView(), 'user' => $user));

    }
```

I have this error : **Neither the property "subForm" nor one of the methods "getSubForm()", "isSubForm()", "hasSubForm()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic".**

Sur the way is wrong, cause i think, I need to give "$topic objexct" and "$post object" when i used : 
**$form = $this->createForm(new TopicType(), $topic);**

And I had tried, with **add(collection)** i get similar error!

Thanks U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because you don't have "subform" attribute in your topic class. That name should correspond to the name of the attribute in your topic class.

So this:

```
->add('subForm', new PostType())
```

Should be changed to

```
$builder->add('posts','collection', array(  'type' => new PostType()))
```

[This](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Abdelaziz Dabebi, now i have `The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post, but is an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection to an instance of BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post. ` but i don't know where i need to put data_class = null, in the setdefaultOption or in the buildForm

Comment: oh my bad. I forgot about your OneToMany relation. Answer updated.